# Identify waterside building / skyline

Tags: identify-this, architecture, cities, landmarks

Among a friend's photos on Facebook I spotted an interesting skyline with a distinctive waterside building that looks like it's just being completed:

[image: distinctive waterside building]

I've travelled to over fifty countries and I can't tell where this is. Can somebody identify the city and/or the building?

(Yes I know I could just ask him but this way I get to share my curiosity.)

Comment: normally, just go to http://images.google.com -- sadly it  had no good results, I saw, in this case.  (As hippie says below.)

Comment: http://tineye.com has an excellent tool that helps identify images.  In this case, it has no result which indicates the photo couldn't be matched to any other photos; however many times the site works wonders.

Comment: @MaxVernon: I tried Google image search and TinEye. TinEye seems to manage only for edited versions of the very same image and not different photos of the same subject. Google image search didn't work with my image combined with "Denmark" or "Aarhus" but it does work combined with "Isbjerget" now that we know what it's called (-:

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is an [apartment complex built on the waterfront of Aarhus in Denmark](http://www.gizmag.com/isbjerget-iceberg-apartments/26775/).

> Isbjerget was created in a collaboration between four architectural
>   firms: JDS, CEBRA, SeARCH, and Louis Paillard. It took 5 years for the
>   project to be completed, and is one of the first projects to be
>   completed within De Bynære Havnearealer, the new docklands quarter of
>   the city. The area was once a container port but is now being
>   transformed into a sprawling development designed to house 7,000
>   inhabitants and provide 12,000 jobs

Comment: Aha! I had a feeling it was Denmark but doing Google image searches with "Denmark" and other hints didn't uncover it.

Comment: Two of my friends looked at apartments there when it opened. They looked really nice and at a reasonable price – but they had weird angled walls and corners, plus the immediate location is not fantastic (right now). In fact, the entire harbour and waterfront area in Aarhus is getting a revamp at the moment, with many new projects. Here is the crown jewel, which is being finished right now: http://www.urbanmediaspace.dk/en

Comment: What a nice church you have.  1500s?